# Specifying window size and other parameters with Titanium.Platform.openURL

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

How do I specify browser window parameters when using Titanium.Platform.openURL ?

These would be the typical browser window parameters such as:

- height
- width
- scrollbars
- toolbar
- status bar
- etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know how to do it is with the Meta tags `apple-mobile-web-app` style.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

May I ask why you are needing to `openURL` instead of a `webView`?